# Jackson Annotation decide on one field class based on another field

Tags: java, jackson

I have multiple implementations for class AbstractAsset

I would like to choose the asset impl based on the type . 
I managed to do so in inheritance and with

> @JsonSubTypes

the problem is , inside couple of the asset I already have the same type string which makes it

```
@Data
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TitleAssetDTO.class, name = "TITLE"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = VideoAssetDTO.class, name = "VIDEO"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ImageAssetDTO.class, name = "IMAGE"),
  @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = DataAssetDTO.class, name = "DATA")
})
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class AbstractAssetDTO {
  @NotNull private String type;
  @NotNull private String key;
}
```

and for instance

```
public class TitleAssetDTO extends AbstractAssetDTO {

  private Title title;

  public Title getTitle() {
    return title;
  }

  public void setTitle(Title title) {
    this.title = title;
  }

  public TitleAssetDTO() {
    this.title = new Title();
  }

  @Data
  public class Title {
    private Integer maxLength;
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public int getMaxLength() {
    return title.maxLength;
  }
}
```

The problem is that other asset types as the type string inside them in the json so I assume that working with inheritance is not the right way to solve this , composite like :

```
class myClass{ 
String type;
AbstractAsset asset;
}
```

would be a better way to implement this , how can I do so ?

Comment: Could you create a simple example what does not work and how to reproduce it? What a problem do you have with `myClass`? Why you added `type` if `asset` already has a `type` and you do not need to duplicate it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a name collision with `type` field. Then just use different name for type prop:
`@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "@type")`